# JW Player playing in background (iMac Safari)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, macos, safari, jwplayer

I am using JW Player with Bootstrap Modal Popup. When pause the video before closing the Modal is working really fine and no issue with that. But when I close the Modal Popup while video is playing, I am pausing the video (`jwplayer("myPlayer").pause()`). But in Safari(iMac), when close the Modal, Modal is closing but audio is playing in background.

How can I stop this ? Here is the code

```
$('#openModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    jwplayer('myPlayer').pause();
});
```

This code is not working in **Safari** only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using jwplayer().stop()?

Comment: Of course I did. It works for milliseconds and once the modal is closed, it starts play again.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jwplayer("myelement").setup({

 autostart: 'false'

});
```